# Building a schedule app - best design pattern for collection on Rails API

Tags: web-api, ruby-on-rails, postgres

I’m building a web app using Rails API on server side. The goal is to make a planning manager. I want my users to be able to plan ‘daily’ events, which will display at some specific weekdays, with some specific member in charge.

Here’s a quick example about what data should look like :

```
event_name
- Monday with UserC
- Wednesday with UserA
```

### Code

I have a collection of events, which looks like following :

event.rb

```rb
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  enum event_type: { punctual: 0, days_of_week: 1, rotative: 2 }
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :event_type, presence: true
end
```

:event_type will link to a more specific table, depending on its value.

### Goal

According to this, I’d like to know which is the best way to design the daily events (event_type: :days_of_week), with the following requirements :

- assign one or multiple users per weekday
- delete a user doesn’t delete the event. If no user is left for a weekday, it disappears from the event
- being able to update the event by adding new members to a day, wether it was already assigned or not

### I tried

I thought of two solutions, but can’t decide which one is better, or even if one of them is suitable :

1. create a has_many relation for event_type: :days_of-week, with a daily table, in which each row contains a day id plus a list of user ids :

```
    Event -> has_many :daily
                - user_id
                - day_id
```

2. create a has_one relation, with a daily table containing 7 columns, each for a specific weekday :

```
Event -> has_one :daily
                - monday = member_id
                - tuesday = member_id
                …
                - sunday = member_id
```

### Thanks in advance for any help!